# Filter json with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter a JSON array. In my example the value of the JSON array is

```
vm.users = [{ "fname": "Antoan", "lname": "Jonson", "Address": "Address1" }, ... ]
```

How can I filter by the last name starts with (for example 'Jo')? I tired this:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', ])
.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $location,  $sce) {
MyApp.filter('myFilter', function () {

    return function (input, term) {
        var output = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function (value, index) {
            if (value.lname.startsWith(term)) {
                output.push(value);
            }
        });
        return output;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a custom filter

```
myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {

return function(input, term) {
    var output=[];
    angular.forEach(input,function(value,index){
        if(value.lname.startsWith(term)){
            output.push(value);
        }
    });
    return output;
}
});
```

then call it with

```
var filtered = $filter('myFilter')(JSON.parse(vm.users), term);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is giving me errors. Do I need to declare the top part as a function.

Comment: app will be your application name and you need to declare it

Comment: I changed my code above. Could you validate if I am doing it right? I still get an error on the return part.

Comment: Basic filter: `function filterByStartsWith(l,k,s){return l.filter(e => e[k].startsWith(s));}`

Comment: Thank you. I got the error that 'MyApp is undefined' when I use your code in the controller as showed above

Comment: replace it with your app name

Comment: I created a function with your example and it is working. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
vm.users.filter(function (user) {
  return user.lname.includes(term);
});
```

Hope this helps.